# array as function argument

Tags: c, arrays

consider the following code:

```
#define MAX_COUNT 4
static int foo(int w[MAX_COUNT])
{
    int *p = w;

    if (w) {
        w[0] = 10; w[1] = 20; w[2] = 30; w[3] = 40;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

is it portable and legal pass NULL to above defined foo() (for example, for a situation when I don't need w[] be altered)? Given that the name of an array is a pointer to its first element, it seems to me that it should be OK, but perhpas I'm missing something?

Thanks !

Comment: What is the issue that you're facing? Is the program not compiling or is it the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine. The number of elements in the array that you passed are merely a formalism, and not really needed.  `w` is just a pointer to `int`.  There is no other runtime or compilation check.

Answer (score 4):

In C, an array type function parameter is the same as a pointer type, so the following are the same:

```
static int foo(int w[]);
static int foo(int* w);
```

So, yes, it is legal to pass `NULL` to this function.

> Given that the name of an array is a pointer to its first element

Not quite.  An array *decays* to a pointer to its initial element *under most circumstances*, the exceptions being when it is the operand of `sizeof` or the unary `&` operator (the address-of operator).

Comment: More correctly, it is *impossible* to declare a parameter that has array type (and illegal to declare a return value that has array type).

Answer (score 1):

C99 has the construct with the awfull syntax (for your example)

```
static int foo(int w[static MAX_COUNT]);
```

which basically means that the function expects at least `MAX_COUNT`
elements. Calling such a function with NULL would then be considered
as an error.

Unfortunately this feature is not yet widely implemented. e.g `gcc`
and `clang` just accept the syntax but don't do anything useful with the
information.