# sizeof float array, different results, is there any workaround?

Tags: c, arrays, function

I currently am making a function which has a fixed sized `float` array as an input:

```
char foo(float fArr[3]) {
}
```

Before I call that function, I tested the size of the `float` array input.

```
float fArr[3];
int s = sizeof(fArr);
char result;
result = foo(fArr);
```

And that gives me `s=12`.

But when I tried to move the checking in the function itself:

```
char foo(float fArr[3]) {
    int s = sizeof(fArr);
    //do something
}
```

But that gives me `s=4`

I have two questions here:

1. Why is that so?
2. All I want is to check if the user gives float array with sufficient size. Is there any way to enforce this by the signature of the function itself, without additional info from the caller?

For instance, we can make the signature having additional info:

```
char foo(float *fArr, int size_fArr);
```

Then we call it like this

```
float fArr[3];
char result;
result = foo(fArr, sizeof(fArr));
```

But I want to avoid that, if possible, by just using the function signature without additional info from the caller such as `sizeof(fArr)`.

Comment: `float fArr[3]` in argument is equivalent to `float *fArr`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array as function argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673890/array-as-function-argument)

Comment: @MikeCAT ah, too bad... :( that explains.. is there any workaround for this? or I have to depend on the caller to give me the correct size?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely have to depend on the caller to give you the correct size.

Comment: @SteveSummit okay... :( thanks for the confirmation. Perhaps I will just split the function into having three input floats then...

Comment: A pointer is not an array.

Comment: @Olaf which one do you refer to?

Comment: Both actually! See the answer and my comment there.

Comment: @Olaf "both". Sorry, I don't get it... I mean in the context of my question.

Comment: I think @bemul12 's answer _is_ in the context of your question, isn't it?

Comment: @Olaf yes, you are right. It is certainly answering no 1 of my question. I am asking about your comment: what do you refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have the compiler verify the size this way: `char foo(float fArr[3])`.
The compiler interprets this as `char foo(float *fArr)` and completely ignores the number of array elements specified. In the body of the function, `sizeof(fArr)` evaluates to the size of a pointer, 4 bytes on your architecture.

The alternatives you mention in your question are possible, although it is more idiomatic to specify the number of elements instead of the byte size of the array pointed to by a pointer argument.  You would pass this information this way:

```
float fArr[3];
char result;
result = foo(fArr, sizeof(fArr) / sizeof(fArr[0]));
```

In C99, there is a extended syntax for your purpose:

```
char foo(float fArr[static 3]) { ... }
```

This specifies that `fArr` is a pointer to an array of at least 3 `float`s.  Be aware that `sizeof(fArr)` is still the size of a pointer inside the function.  Here is a example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int size(float arr[static 3]) {
    return sizeof(arr);
}

int main(void) {
    float arr1;
    float arr2[2];
    float arr3[3];
    float arr4[4];
    float *arr2p = arr2;

    printf("size(arr1) = %d\n", size(&arr1));
    printf("size(arr2) = %d\n", size(arr2));
    printf("size(arr2p) = %d\n", size(arr2p));
    printf("size(arr3) = %d\n", size(arr3));
    printf("size(arr4) = %d\n", size(arr4));

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `clang -std=c99` produces these diagnostics:

```
arrsta.c:4:22: warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'float *' instead of 'float[static 3]' [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
        return sizeof(arr);
                      ^
arrsta.c:3:20: note: declared here
    int size(float arr[static 3]) {
                   ^
arrsta.c:15:37: warning: array argument is too small; contains 2 elements, callee requires at least 3 [-Warray-bounds]
        printf("size(arr2) = %d\n", size(arr2));
                                    ^    ~~~~
arrsta.c:3:20: note: callee declares array parameter as static here
    int size(float arr[static 3]) {
                   ^  ~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
```

As you can see, if gives you a useful warning about the potential `sizeof(arr)` confusion and it complains if you pass an array that is too short, but it does not if you pass a pointer, even if this pointer is obviously not pointing to an array of sufficient size.  Imperfect, but better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the more complete explanation, Sir. I appreciate it. I will take a look on the static on C99 as you mention. At least, I know that it is the *C standard* which changes my array to pointer. It is not because of my own signature design that it happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
char foo(float fArr[3]){ }
```

is converted to

```
char foo(float * fArr) { }
```

Comment: Nit-pick: It does not translate, but it is "converted to a pointer to the first element"

Comment: Thanks the correction, i didnt use the corresponding word. Sorry for my english. I updated it.

Comment: FYI: The term commonly used is "the array decays to a pointer to ...". Note, however the standard uses the other version. Also note that is not recursive (important for 2+D arrays).

Comment: @bemul12 thanks for the clarification. Do you have any suggestion to work around with it, sir?